# I tried to add a hamburger icon to my website and it messed up my nav now the drop downs are being weird

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to add a burger bar to my navbar and it wouldn’t work and now my navbar doesn’t look great, I want to add the burger bar back in as well as having the drop downs hidden beneath there respected names anyone have any idea how to do this? Also someone mentioned I should be utilizing `<ul>` `<li>` tags but I’ve never used before so do people recommend using them and if I do will I have to edit the CSS or anything?

I tried to add a burger bar for mobile view and it wasn’t responsive and since removing it the drop-down menus have started acting funny and are showing, I may have deleted vital code.

HTML & CSS

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Righteous&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Righteous&display', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: cadetblue;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 99;
}

.navigation a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.navigation a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -8px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.navigation a:hover::after {
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.navigation .btnLogin-popup {
  width: 130px;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid black;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 40px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.navigation .btnLogin-popup:hover {
  background: white;
  color: #162938;
}

.dropdown {
  float: Right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="RRlogo.png" href="Home" alt="RR">

  <div class="navigation">
    <a href="#">SG</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropBtn">Dropdown
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="I.html">I</a>
        <a href="M.html">M</a>
        <a href="R.html">R</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#">T</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropBtn">Dropdown
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="H.html">H</a>
          <a href="T.html">T</a>
        </div>
        <a href="M.html">M</a>
        <a href="S.html">S</a>
        <button class="btnLogin-popup">Login</button>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-telegram"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="#/"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></a>
      </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Constructive Criticism:  You may get better responses if your paragraphs aren't also Road Runners. I suggest breaking them up.  They are a little hard to read as-is.  Also you put `JavaScript` in your tags, but I don't see any attempted JavaScript code?

Comment: Also *"I may have deleted vital code"*  You should have "undo/redo" in your IDE that goes a ways back.  Also whenever making major changes ALWAYS incrementally test, and ALWAYS make a backup of your original so you can start over at any time.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To add a hamburger menu for mobile view that is responsive and hide the dropdown menu items beneath their respective names, there are several steps you'll need to take.

```js
<script>

const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
const navMenu = document.querySelector('.navigation ul');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', function() {
    navMenu.classList.toggle('active');
});
</script>
```

```css
.hamburger {
    display: none;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navigation {
    display: flex;
}

.navigation ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation li {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

/* Mobile view */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navigation {
    width: 100%;
   }

   .navigation ul {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%; 
   }

   .navigation ul.active {
    display: flex;
   }

   .navigation li {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center;
  }

  .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: none;
 }
  }
```

```html
<header>
    <img src="RRlogo.png" alt="RR">

    <button class="hamburger">☰</button>

    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SG</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropBtn">Dropdown<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="I.html">I</a>
                    <a href="M.html">M</a>
                    <a href="R.html">R</a>
                </div>
            </li>
           
            <li><a href="M.html">M</a></li>
            <li><a href="S.html">S</a></li>
            <li><button class="btnLogin-popup">Login</button></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-telegram"></i></a></li>
          
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Code only answers are not considered to be good answers on Stack Overflow. You should be including what the original problem was and how your code solves it.

Comment: Hi that code works great your a lifesaver, just a question on the js code it’s saying there’s a error on the > symbol of the (‘click’ , () => { line do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: The error you're encountering is likely due to an incompatibility with arrow functions. Arrow functions (() => {}) are a part of ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) and are not supported in older browsers, most notably Internet Explorer. If you want to ensure better compatibility across browsers, especially older ones, you can use a regular function instead of the arrow function.

Comment: I’ve got a lot of the same sort of script further up it’s just saying - did you mean {‘>’} or &gt; ? Whatever this means

Comment: Never mind was a mistake on my behalf, had to delete the <script></script>

Comment: When I open the burger bar the nav links open to the right of it they don’t drop beneath it in a menu is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Absolutely. The issue arises due to the CSS properties we've set for desktop view which is still being applied in mobile view. The dropdown menu items are not taking up the full width and are being positioned in a row because of the flex properties we've set. I will modify the css

Comment: Sorry only just seen this I’ve implemented the edited css code but it’s just making the burger icon disappear for some reason